# Xquery All Function

Tags: xquery

This'll probably seem like a stupid question, but I've been Googling for fifteen minutes and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.  I to determine if all of the nodes in a particular set return true for a given predicate.  For example, if I have a set of integer nodes, I might want to know if all of them are greater than 5.  This seems simple enough, but I can't seem to find a keyword or function to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called Quantified Expressions. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions

> Quantified expressions support
>   existential and universal
>   quantification. The value of a
>   quantified expression is always true
>   or false.
>
> `QuantifiedExpr    ::=    ("some" |
>   "every") "$" VarName "in" ExprSingle
>   ("," "$" VarName "in" ExprSingle)*
>   "satisfies" ExprSingle`

This XQuery expression:

```
every $num in /test/num/number() satisfies $num gt 5
```

With this input:

```
<test>
  <num>3</num>
  <num>4</num>
  <num>5</num>
</test>
```

Result:

```
false
```

**Note**: XQuery 1.0 is a superset of XPath 2.0